# How do I refactor this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have following MySQL query:

```
(SELECT c.Channel as name, count(*) as total_episode
 FROM (
     SELECT a.aid, a.vid 
     FROM videoItem v INNER JOIN aid2vid a USING(vid) 
     GROUP BY a.aid
 ) a1 INNER JOIN channelListingItem c USING(aid) 
 GROUP BY c.Channel
) 
UNION 
(SELECT c1.Channel as name, 0 as total_episode
 FROM channelListingItem c1 LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT c.Channel FROM (
         SELECT a.aid, a.vid 
         FROM videoItem v INNER JOIN aid2vid a USING(vid) 
         GROUP BY a.aid
     ) a1 INNER JOIN channelListingItem c USING(aid) 
     GROUP BY c.Channel
 ) c2 USING(Channel) 
 WHERE c2.Channel is null 
 GROUP BY name
);
```

Basically, what this statement does is to get the correct count episode in each channel & assign zero for channels w/o vid in consequent table (videoItem).

Note that

```
SELECT a.aid, a.vid
FROM videoItem v
INNER JOIN aid2vid a USING(vid)
GROUP BY a.aid
```

is duplicated twice and from explain this MySQL statement I don't see MySQL re-use the query result.

```
+----+--------------+------------+------+----------+---------+---------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type | pos_keys | key     | key_len | ref      | rows | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+------------+------+----------+---------+---------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |  313 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | c          | ALL  | idx_vid  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |  616 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  2 | DERIVED      | a          | ALL  | vid      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | 1015 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED      | v          | ref  | idx_vid  | idx_vid | 32      | db.a.vid |   10 | Using index                     |
|  3 | UNION        | c1         | ALL  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |  616 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | UNION        | <derived4> | ALL  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |   28 | Using where; Not exists         |
|  4 | DERIVED      | <derived5> | ALL  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |  313 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  4 | DERIVED      | c          | ALL  | idx_vid  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |  616 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  5 | DERIVED      | a          | ALL  | vid      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | 1015 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  5 | DERIVED      | v          | ref  | idx_vid  | idx_vid | 32      | db.a.vid |   10 | Using index                     |
|NULL| UNION RESULT | <union1,3> | ALL  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | NULL |                                 |
+----+--------------+------------+------+----------+---------+---------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

How do I refactor this MySQL statement? Also is there good refactor tool for MySQL statement?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Why do you want to refactor?

Comment: You can try Toad for Mysql tool, it's freeware.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: explain result attached.

Comment: @rkosegi: just tried Toad. although it does not help a lot (maybe i just play it for 5 mins), thanks for tool suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seemed to work for me:

```
select Channel as name,count(distinct a1.aid) as total_episode
from channelListingItem c
left join
(
 select a.aid, a.vid 
 from videoItem v INNER JOIN aid2vid a USING(vid) 
) a1 on a1.aid = c.aid
group by Channel;
```

From what I can see the following query that you use twice in an inline view:

```
SELECT a.aid, a.vid 
FROM videoItem v INNER JOIN aid2vid a USING(vid) 
GROUP BY a.aid
```

Is being used to get a distinct list of `aid` and `vid` values that exist in both `videoItem` and `aid2vid`. I have replaced the `GROUP BY` in the inline view with a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` to achieve the same thing since you are not using any aggregate functions in the inline view part of the query.

I think you do not need to split the query into two parts joined by a union i.e. part 1 to get episode counts > 0 and part 2 to get episode counts = 0. This can be achieved in one `GROUP BY`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works for me too. Although the one below using COALESCE produces w/ same result, MySQL explain seems favor with this answer. So I choice this one.

Answer (score 1):

I could be way of but I believe following to provide the same results as your original query does.

The gist of it is to

- Add the `total_episode` field to your `LEFT JOIN`.
- Use `COALESCE` to return either the `total_episode` value or `0`.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  c1.Channel as name
        , COALESCE(total_episode, 0)
FROM    channelListingItem c1 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
          SELECT  c.Channel
                  , count(*) as total_episode
          FROM    (
                    SELECT  a.aid
                            , a.vid 
                    FROM    videoItem v 
                            INNER JOIN aid2vid a ON a.vid = v.vid
                    GROUP BY 
                            a.aid
                   ) a1 
                  INNER JOIN channelListingItem c ON c.aid = a1.aid
          GROUP BY 
                  c.Channel
         ) c2 ON c2.Channel = c1.Channel
  GROUP BY 
        name
```